# Prevent the Repetition of Data in Database

Tags: python, django

Here's the code in view,

```
def index(request):
    data = Model.objects.create(user=request.user, timestamp=timezone.now())
```

Whenever the view is requested i'm saving the user requesting it & the timestamp at which user has requested the page.

But, It's repeating the same data in database with updated timestamp. How can I prevent the repetition by updating the same instance when the view is requested?

Please helpme!

Comment: So you want to only update the timestamp if the record exists and if the record does not exist, you want to create a new one?

Comment: @Kyle Yes Sir absolutely. I used an Try & Except along-with If & Else since if & else since it was not creating a new one for a fresh user, on the answer of Sir Astik Anand. Is it a right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle using this way. If data is not there then create else update.

```
def index(request):
    data = Model.objects.update_or_create(user=request.user, timestamp=timezone.now())
```

> Alternatively:

```
def index(request):

    data = Model.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if not data:
        data = Model.objects.create(user=request.user, timestamp=timezone.now())
    else:
        data = Model.objects.update(user=request.user, timestamp=timezone.now())
```

Comment: Thank You Sir. Working Fine along-with a Try & Except with the above "data" variable since it was raising an error & not creating an instance for a new user :) Is it a good way to use Try & Except as well ?

Comment: Actually I tried using `try` and `except` only and that's the better way. You can check the `edit history` of answer. But then I thought to go by above . But it is better to go with `try` and `except` coz I always prefer that way.